Link to BE module "page layout" with "close button" in TYPO3
Make it possible to link to the Backend module page layout (/web/layout) in TYPO3, with a return URL and a close button.
In particular, I have a list (e.g. like the list of broken links in linkvalidator) and want to jump to the page layout view, but make it possible to jump back again - otherwise it is very awkward, if you jump to the view and then can't jump back.

The left button will jump to the page layout view, but then there is no button to close or go back.
The right button will open an edit form where we also have a "Close" button. This is what I want for the other one as well.
<f:variable name="link"><be:moduleLink route="web_layout" arguments="{id: element.pid, returnUrl: returnUrl}">layout</be:moduleLink></f:variable>
<a href="{link}" class="btn btn-default" title="page layout">
  <core:icon identifier="actions-document" size="small"/>
</a>
<be:link.editRecord class="btn btn-primary" title="edit"                                                     uid="{element.uid}" table="tt_content" returnUrl="{returnUri}">
  <core:icon identifier="actions-document-edit" size="small"/>
</be:link.editRecord>

The "returnUrl" has already been created correctly in the Controller.
I have investigated: both Viewhelpers will use UriBuilder::buildUriFromRoute which accepts a list of parameters, including returnUrl. So the problem is probably, that the page layout does not consider the possibility it was opened from elsewhere and a close button should be displayed. But I assume, this can be done, just not sure how.

TYPO3 v11 and above.

Assuming you use TYPO3 12. (Please always add informations about you running system when asking questions.)
Taking a look at the PageLayoutController:
TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Controller\PageLayoutController
It seems that there is no Close/Return Link you can use.
But the Event "ModifyPageLayoutContentEvent" is fired in the mainAction of the controller.
You could use this event to implement your close/return link.
For that you need register an event-listener in:
your-ext/Configuration/Services.yaml
Like that:
services:
  VENDOR\YourExt\EventListener\PageLayoutListener:
    tags:
      - name: event.listener
        identifier: your-ext/page-layout-listener

And then you can implement the event-listener like that:
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
namespace VENDOR\YourExt\EventListener;

use TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Controller\Event\ModifyPageLayoutContentEvent;
use TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Template\Components\ButtonBar;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\Icon;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconFactory;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;

class PageLayoutListener
{
    public function __invoke(ModifyPageLayoutContentEvent $event): void
    {
        // here, we could use the referer URL or get the returnUrl argument which was passed to the ViewHelper 
        //$refererUrl = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
        $returnUrl = $event->getRequest()->getQueryParams()['returnUrl'] ?? '';  

        // Somehow you need to check from which Page you come,
        // so that the Close-Link is not shown, when opening the web/layout module directly
        // Here its assumed that the referer URL is the linkvalidator-reports page
        // You need at least PHP 8 when using str_contains function. If you run PHP<8 you need to use substr or other function
        // use str_contains to check for specific module or check returnUrl
        //if(str_contains($refererUrl, 'typo3/module/page/link-reports')) {
        if ($returnUrl) {
            $view = $event->getModuleTemplate();
            $buttonBar = $view->getDocHeaderComponent()->getButtonBar();
            $iconFactory = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(IconFactory::class);

            $returnButton = $buttonBar->makeLinkButton()
                //->setHref($refererUrl)
                ->setHref($returnUrl)  
                ->setTitle('Close')  // Here you could use translation if needed like this: $this->getLanguageService()->sL('LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_core.xlf:labels.showPage')
                ->setIcon($iconFactory->getIcon('actions-close', Icon::SIZE_SMALL))  // Create your custom icon or use any of the alredy created icons
                ->setShowLabelText(true);
            $buttonBar->addButton($returnButton, ButtonBar::BUTTON_POSITION_LEFT, 0);
        }
    }
}

EDIT:
In TYPO3 < 12 you can use the "drawHeaderHook" to do the same. Did not test it, but the View is also passed in the hook. Should be available by getModuleTemplate function.
In TYPO3 11.5.36 the hook is implemented in Line 732 of the PageLayoutController:
https://github.com/TYPO3-CMS/backend/blob/10bdd68cc1b35e71779511192219ba35a287b42b/Classes/Controller/PageLayoutController.php#L732

Thanks, I am using v11. I added it above but said v11 and above. I will probably use this for v12 and up since the event is not supported for lower versions.

The solution basically works (I tested with brofix + TYPO3 v12). It would have been nice to show the button if a returnUrl was passed to the page layout and return to the returnUrl on close (and not make it depend on some module since I would like to use it for other extensions as well) but since unfortunately this information is not returned with the event that is not possible this way.  I will look into adding this in a patch for v13

Updated my Answer for TYPO3 < 12.
Hope you find a solution for using it for multiple extensions.

It is possible to get the returnUrl in the event listener: $event->getRequest()->getQueryParams()['returnUrl'] ?? ''; This way - with slight modifications - it is the solution I had in mind.

Yes - Great idea to pass the returnUrl in the Request query data. Would be a good feature Request for v13 for the PagelayoutController: If ReturnUrl passed in Query - Show Return Link. :-)

I made edits to use the returnUrl and change icon. Hope its ok for you

Happy with that. Now the code is even better. Thats what open source is all about. :-)
